# Can I modify this bluetooth keyboard to only have a certain keys so I can carry it around?

Tags: bluetooth, android, camera, iphone

I'm trying to make a bluetooth remote shutter release thing for Androird and iOS. I asked about doing it from scratch but everyone thinks it's too ambitious for a beginner, so I gave up on that

Few days ago I acquired a bluetooth silicone keyboard that is still functioning(tested it with iOS and Android; able to get both phones to take pics)

My question is now, can I modify the board or he circuit so I only keep the buttons I want so I can carry it around? the keyboard is attached in the link

[image]

(for iOS it's the Volume Down key, and for Android it's the Enter key)

thanks for the advices and tips!

Comment: I think that'll be do-able... You'll need to trace the connections from your 2 buttons of interest back to the connector on the PCB and then solder a pair of your own buttons across those connections.

Comment: thanks! is the pcb the mainboard or the rollable part that's sitting under the silicone keyboard? i can solder stuff to the plastic rolling part?

Comment: The PCB is the rigid green board with components soldered to it. You can't solder to the plastic bit - once you've figured out which of the silver tracks inside it correspond to the buttons you're interested in, you can unplug it from the PCB.

Comment: @brhans thanks again! pardon my ignorance, but how is the pcb able to map all the keys from the keyboard? there are only 26 pins, and one of them doesn't lead to anywhere, and there are way more than 26 keys on the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

I think that will probably work for what you want to use it for.

You'll need to trace the connections from your 2 buttons of interest back to the connector on the PCB and then solder a pair of your own buttons across those connections (the PCB is the rigid green board with components soldered to it).

You can't solder to the flexible plastic part, but that doesn't matter since once you've figured out which of the silver tracks inside it correspond to the buttons you're interested in and which pins on the connector they lead to, you can unplug it from the PCB since you won't need it anymore.

You're wondering how the electronics on the PCB manages to map all of the keys using a much smaller number of pins?
The answer is that the keys are arranged in a matrix, so each of the pins is actually shared between multiple keys.
If you imagine a simpler matrix of 12 buttons like you might find on a phone, you don't need 12 connections to read them - you only need 7.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frLeyL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This does sometimes create some issues, for example if SW1 and SW5 are both pressed at the same time it could be a bit more difficult to read, but there are ways around this.